# Angular View: access current node

Tags: angularjs

I have the following view:

```
<div ng-class="setClass($currentNode)">{{setContent($currentNode)}}</div>
```

With the following controller:

```
$scope.setClass = function(currentNode) {
  // Process with angular.element(currentNode);
}

$scope.setContent = function(currentNode) {
  // Process with angular.element(currentNode);
}
```

Can I access the `$currentNode` in which the method is called? From `setClass`? From `setContent`? Both?

Thanks

---

## EDIT

Thanks for reply and comments. I know what I am doing, so I'll explain further.

I have in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-class="setClass(element)">{{setValue(element)}}</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.setValue = function(element) {
  return callOfAFunctionThatRequiresSomeHardComputation(element);
}

$scope.setClass = function(element) {
  return callOfAFunctionThatRequiresSomeHardComputation(element) > 0 ? 'active' : '';
}
```

I don't want to calculate `callOfAFunctionThatRequiresSomeHardComputation` 2 times on every `$digest` cycle because it is pretty heavy to compute already.

So I'd rather write:

```
$scope.setValue = function(element, $currentNode) {
  var result = callOfAFunctionThatRequiresSomeHardComputation(element);
  if (result > 0) {
    angular.element($currentNode).addClass('active');
  } else {
    angular.element($currentNode).removeClass('active');
  }
  return result;
}
```

I understand that beginners could miss the *angular-way* easily, but it doesn't mean it is not worth learning how to do it.

Comment: This is not how you do things in Angular. Don't know what you are trying to do, but believe me, you don't need current element. Try to explain better your purpose, to get better solution.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: _I don't want to calculate ... 2 times_ - Then cache the result.

Comment: Since it is in a `elements` loop, it means I need to calculate the result and to map it to each element with a unique identifier, which to me seems much dirtier than what I am suggesting. Anyways, the question is **how** to do it, and not **why** doing this.

Answer (score 0):

An angular way to do this would be like this :

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{{myclass}}">{{mycontent}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.myclass="a-class";
$scope.mycontent="acontent";
```

If your want to manage more elements just use a ng-repeat to copy the html element for each items in an array.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.content}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.items = [{
   class:"Class1",
   content:"Content1",
},{
   class:"Class2",
   content:"Content2",
}];
```

Hope it helped. If you anymore question feel free.